# Median of Dataset in Mathematica 10

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, dataset

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.3**

---

I'm having trouble calculating the median of a `Dataset[]` in *Mathematica* 10.

The situation is as follows. Consider a dataset that was defined as follows:

```
dataset = Dataset[{<|"a"->1,"b"->2|>,<|"a"->3,"b"->4|>}];
```

The mean and variance of columns `a` and `b` can now be calculated by

```
mean = dataset[Mean, {"a","b"}]
var = dataset[Variance, {"a","b"}]
```

That works pefectly, but

```
med = dataset[Median, {"a","b"}]
```

returns a `Failure[]`! Somehow, `Median[]` is not compatible with a list of associations as its argument and the other functions are.

Can someone explain why this happens and maybe help with a solution?

Comment: I found a workaround. Entering `AssociationThread[Keys[#[[1]]], Median[Values /@ #]]&` instead of `Median` helps. But I must say that I don't like this at all, there should be a better way.

Comment: A couple of questions. What OS are you using? Also, what do you mean by "crash"? Does the kernel go down? Or, do you get a `Failure[...]`? On Mac OS, I get a failure.

Comment: You're right. It returns a Failure. I updated the question. I'm on OS X as well.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Have you reported this to support@wolfram.com?

Comment: It's not that `Median` isn't compatible with associations, its that the type here is recognized as a `Struct` instead of an `Assoc`. That's not wrong, per se, but it does mean that the type inference scheme, which is a vast undertaking that can never really be finished, doesn't 'know' that this should be allowed. There is a fairly straightforward fix that may make it into 10.0.1 (and will fix many similar issues), but for now, writing `Median[#]&` instead of `Median` should get around this problem. Edit: I'm wrong, `Median` *doesn't* work properly on associations of vectors.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon, possibly related issue (same workaround): SplitBy also doesn't have an operator form. Reference page hasn't been updated for 10. Can you please report to WRI?

Comment: @alancalvitti will do, thanks!

Comment: Worth noting this is still present in 10.0.2

Comment: Another way is `Transpose[dataset][All, Median]`.

Answer (score 2):

Working since version 10.3:

```
dataset = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 4|>}];

med = dataset[Median, {"a", "b"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Median itself doesn't work on associations of vectors:

```
In[9]:= Median[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 4|>}]
During evaluation of In[9]:= Median::rectn: Rectangular array of real numbers is expected at position 1 in Median[{<|a->1,b->2|>,<|a->3,b->4|>}]. >>
Out[9]= Median[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 4|>}]
```

Comment: This kind of makes sense because the median is defined based on ordering of the elements.  Vectors cannot be ordered, thus mathematically the median of vectors makes no sense.  `Median` does have the convenient behaviour that for a list of vectors `Median[list]` gives `Median /@ Transpose[list]` though.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes I agree. Reported as 297160.