# MedianDeviation upsets Dataset in 10.3.1

Tags: probability-or-statistics, dataset

This seemingly innocent piece of code seems to choke the interpreter somewhere...

```
Dataset[Association[{"x"->1.0#}]&/@Range[5]][Association[{"Mean"->1000 Mean[#],"StandardDeviation"->10000 StandardDeviation[#],"Median"->10000 Median[#], "MedianDeviation"->MedianDeviation[#]}]&]
```

If would appear that the problem is the calculation of MedianDeviation since removing this item calculation allows the rest of the code to run.

10.3.1 running in the cloud.

Possibly another occurrence of or similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57281/median-of-dataset-in-mathematica-10) previous bug with Median in a Dataset.

Can someone confirm in the desktop application?

Comment: Confirmed in 10.3.1.

Comment: Also in 10.4, with the message Rectangular array of real numbers is expected at position 1 in MedianDeviation[{<|x->1.|>,<|x->2.|>,<|x->3.|>,<|x->4.|>,<|x->5.|>}]. So at the moment it seems that MedianDeviation cannot have an association as an argument.