# Variance of list of associations

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.4 and fixed in 11.1**

---

`Mean` can calculate the mean of a list of associations:

```
Mean[{<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3|>}]
```

gives `<|"a" -> 2|>` as expected. But

```
Variance[{<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3|>}]
```

gives `<|"a" -> <|"a" -> 1|>|>`, instead of the expected `<|"a" -> 1|>`. Is this a bug?

I am using Mathematica 11.0 on Windows 7.

---

The obvious workaround is to use the explicit expression for the variance in terms of the mean,

```
With[{list = {<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3|>}},
    (Mean[list^2] - Mean[list]^2) Length[list]/(Length[list] - 1)]
```

which gives `<|"a" -> 1|>` as expected.

---

The bug identified in [Median of Dataset in Mathematica 10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57281/median-of-dataset-in-mathematica-10) is closely related but (I think) distinct.

Comment: this issue seems to be  fixed in v 11.2.